# verificar si un archivo ya ah sido descargado en swift 3

Tags: swift3

Tengo un método para descargar un json desde una url y funciona correctamente, me descarga el archivo y me imprime la ruta en donde ah sido guardado, pero ahora no se como implementar un método para verificar que si el archivo ya existe, no se vuelva a descargar y si no, que entre al método para descargar, tambien quisiera cambiar la ruta de donde se guarda el archivo. Espero puedan ayudarme, Gracias.

Les dejo lo que tengo.

=========================================================================

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//Create URL to the source file you want to download
let fileURL = URL(string: "http://10.32.14.124:7098/Servicio.svc/getCentralesMovilJSON/")

// Create destination URL
let documentsUrl:URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



}

func descargar() {



    //agregar al destino el archivo
    let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("centrales.json")

    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)

    let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)

    let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
        if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
            // Success
            if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
                print(destinationFileUrl)
            }

            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
            } catch (let writeError) {
                print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
            }

        } else {
            print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

estuve investigando y logre resolver mi duda, ahora ya puedo verificar si mi archivo existe, solo me manda la ruta en donde se encuentra guardado y si no, lo descarga....

aqui esta mi nuevo código

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 //llamar metodo para descargar json
        descargar()

}

//------------------Descargar archivo------------------------------------------------------------
func descargar() {


    //Create URL to the source file you want to download
    let fileURL = URL(string: "http://10.32.14.124:7098/Servicio.svc/getCentralesMovilJSON/")

    // Create destination URL
    let documentsUrl:URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!

    //agregar al destino el archivo
    let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("centrales.json")

    //archivo existente???....................................................
    let fileExists = FileManager().fileExists(atPath: destinationFileUrl.path)

    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)

    let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)

    // si el archivo ya existe, no descargarlo de nuevo y enviar ruta de destino.........................................................................
    if fileExists == true {
        print("archivo existente")
        print(destinationFileUrl    )
    }

// si el archivo aun no existe, descargarlo y mostrar ruta de destino..........................................................................
    else{
        print("descargar archivo")



    let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
        if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
            // Success se ah descargado correctamente...................................
            if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
                print(destinationFileUrl)
            }

            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
            } catch (let writeError) {
                print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
            }

        } else {
            print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
        }
        }
    task.resume()

    }}

}
```